# Raise event several times while Mouse held down

Tags: c#, event-handling, mouseevent

Basically let's say I'm making a simple counter, when I click the mouse, the counter goes up. My question is how do I program an even that makes it possible for me to have the counter flowing while the mouse I held down, basically something that works exactly as the KeyPress event handler, only with a mouse.

Comment: I don't think the MouseDown event will fire continuously, so use it in conjunction with a Timer to do the counting .. make sure to *not* block any events or the UI will stop being responsive (please no suggestions for DoEvents here!). That is, there should be *no* do/while loops in this approach.

Comment: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons(v=vs.100).aspx) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a timer running for some other reason, I wouldn't use a timer. I would use a class property or global variable, depending on what you're doing.

```
private/public startTicks long = 0;
```

When you fire the MouseDown event:

`startTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;`

On the MouseUp event, take the difference and convert it to whatever time element (min, sec, hour) you want.

```
DoConversion(DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTicks);
```

Comment: Yatrix, thanks that got me started, however I also want the label to show the counter going up as the mouse button is pushed down, that's how it works for KeyPressed. Any idea for that?

Comment: For that, you will probably need a timer to update it in defined intervals.

Comment: @AndrewB If I answered your question, please upvote and accept the answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a solution based on using [Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads).

I've assumed that the `MouseDown` & `MouseUp` events are based on clicking the form and that there is a `NumericUpDown` control that we wish to increment every 0.1 seconds while the mouse is down.

Here's the Reactive Framework way of coding the solution:

```
var mouseDowns = Observable.FromEventPattern
    <MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
        h => this.MouseDown += h,
        h => this.MouseDown -= h);

var mouseUps = Observable.FromEventPattern
    <MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
        h => this.MouseUp += h,
        h => this.MouseUp -= h);

var intervals = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));

var query =
    from md in mouseDowns
    select intervals.TakeUntil(mouseUps);

query.Switch().ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(n => numericUpDown1.Value += 1);
```

The reactive query should be very easy to understand its purpose - basically it is "When you get a mouse down select the intervals until there is a mouse up."

The type of `query` is `IObservable<IObservable<long>>` so before the `Subscribe` we need to call `Switch` to turn the query into an `IObservable<long>`.

The `ObserveOn(this)` makes sure that the values of the observable are marshalled to the UI thread.

Rx can be a little tricky to learn, but once you've got it it is very powerful. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Define a timer that starts firing its events when the `MouseDown` event occurs. Then set the `MouseUp` event to pause or stop the timer. Execute the code you want to be triggered when the timer elapses.